# How do I get RubyMine to recognize Twitter-Bootstrap variables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, rubymine

Ideally I would like intellij to work with this but just getting them to be recognized as acceptable is the next best thing.
Example:

```
$white
$grayLight
```

etc.

Thanks :)

Comment: Could be http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-11241

Comment: Thanks! My understanding of that is the variables are within imported files of bootstrap and thus can't be seen by RubyMine?

The solution to cross include necessary files was confusing to me, do I need to find the specific files within bootstrap containing the color variables even though they are found when the script is run?

Thanks for the quick response :)

Comment: @fatlad the colors variables are in variables.less https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/less/variables.less

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to CrazyCoder and baptme I found

http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-5342?query=with

which gave me some hints to fiddle around with.

I found that each .scss file has to be included manually.

To find the file I ctrl clicked on "bootstrap" in

```
@import "bootstrap"
```

though ctrl+shft+r and then typing in _variables probably works as well.

For example my import looked like this:

```
@import "C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bootstrap-sass-2.0.3.1/vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_variables.scss";
```

TLDR: You need to import each .scss file you are referencing because RubyMine will not automatically search through all directory files.

Comment: Fugly, but works. Thanks for this, @Fatlad. I wish Rubymine would fix this soon.